# How component scan in spring?Is it initialize all object as singleton or it lazy initialize?

Tags: java, spring

I want to know about how spring servlet component scan works? and it scan @Service,@Component etc scan.But I am not clear how it works? What flow works behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**How component scan in spring?**](https://www.altamiracorp.com/blog/employee-posts/just-how-does-spring-do)

It boils down to doing some gymnastics with class loaders and resource path matching and using the `ClassLoader.getResources(String name)` method which returns an `Enumeration` containing URLs representing classpath resources. Those resources (Java classes) are then checked to see if they contain the @Component annotation (or a specialization of it) and if so, are considered a "candidate" component. Other filtering can take place but by default those components are then defined programmatically as Spring beans. When annotation configuration is enabled, autowiring of components also takes place, so I can have Spring scan the classpath for all my web controllers, and then automatically inject dependencies such as services or data access objects.

The actual classes that perform this magic are the `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` which, by default, uses a PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver to find matching classpath resources using `ClassLoader.getResources()`.

---

As per [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s12.html) Spring beans are singletons by default.

> As with Spring-managed components in general, the default and by far
>   most common scope is 'singleton'. However, there are times when other
>   scopes are needed. Therefore Spring 2.5 introduces a new @Scope
>   annotation as well. Simply provide the name of the scope within the
>   annotation

```
@Scope(StandardScopes.PROTOTYPE)
@Repository
public class MovieFinderImpl implements MovieFinder {
    // ...
}
```

Different Bean scopes are avialable [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html).

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do when you're curious about how something is implemented in an open source project is to look at the source code.  Here's how I would go about it.  These steps are specific to my particular configuration (XML based Spring contexts written with Eclipse) but the general theory is applicable to any environment....

1) I know from poking around the source code that the classes that parse particular XML config elements usually have a name that ends with "BeanDefinitionParser".  So to see how:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourproject" />
```

is implemented, look for classes named "Component*BeanDefinitionProcessor".

2) Doing a CTRL + SHIFT + T in Eclipse and searching for "Component*BeanDefinitionProcessor" I came up with [ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-maintenance/trunk/tiger/src/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java?hb=true).  That sounds like it's probably what I'm looking for...

3) Within that class (lines 83 - 85), there's this chunk of code:

```
ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner scanner = configureScanner(parserContext, element);
Set<BeanDefinitionHolder> beanDefinitions = scanner.doScan(basePackages);
registerComponents(parserContext.getReaderContext(), beanDefinitions, element);
```

So the class that processes  XML tags delegates to ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.  This makes sense since Spring supports both XML configuration as well as Java based configuration.  It wouldn't make sense to duplicate the actual scanning logic in the annotations config handler and the XML config handler.

4) Looking at the code for ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner, I don't see anything that looks like it's looking for things on the classpath.  However, it does extend a class named [ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-maintenance/trunk/tiger/src/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java?r=16818).

```
public class ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner extends ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider {
```

5) Looking in ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider, I can see the for loop that's looping over everything in a package

```
public Set<BeanDefinition> findCandidateComponents(String basePackage) {
    Set<BeanDefinition> candidates = new LinkedHashSet<BeanDefinition>();

    try {
        String packageSearchPath = ResourcePatternResolver.CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX +
        resolveBasePackage(basePackage) + "/" + this.resourcePattern;

        Resource[] resources = this.resourcePatternResolver.getResources(packageSearchPath);

        boolean traceEnabled = logger.isTraceEnabled();
        boolean debugEnabled = logger.isDebugEnabled();

        for (int i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
```

6) It's using ResourcePatternResolver to find stuff on the classpath:

```
private ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
```

7) In PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver you can see the code that actually searches the classpath.